# How to detect footer content of an embed Discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I was looking to get the footer of an embed, i tried doing this but didnt work, any help?

```
for (var i = 0; i < message.embeds.length; i++) {
if (message.embeds[i] &&
    message.embeds[i].footer &&
    message.embeds[i].footer.includes('test')) {
      //do stuffs

     }
}
```

Comment: Its probably a good idea to output (via `console.log()`) the embeds to see what is actually there. In theory, `message.embeds[i].footer`should work.

Answer (score 0):

Ok i got the answer:-

```
for (var i = 0; i < message.embeds.length; i++) {
  if (message.embeds[i] &&
  message.embeds[i].footer &&
  message.embeds[i].footer.text.includes('test')) {
  //do stuffs

 }
```

}